# android older vs newer version

Tags: android, variables, canvas, draw

I am a bit confused about the way my code works in android 3 and android 4. I am trying to take a picture every 2 seconds, every time find it's Hue and Lum then use these numbers as X and Y coords in a canvasView to draw a cross on a map. The terrible way I use works fine in android 3. Here are chunks of my code.

```
   //this is the Activity to take the picture
    public class ProcessAnalyser extends Activity implements OnClickListener,
    SurfaceHolder.Callback, Camera.PictureCallback {

    ... declare a bunch of variables here
    static double H, L;

    public void onPictureTaken(final byte[] data, Camera camera) {
    ...code here
    H = some value;
    L = some value;
    }
```

after long RGB work the H and L get some values which I access from the next class

```
  // this View draws the cross on a canvas
  public class CanvasView extends View  {
  Bitmap bmp;
  float X, Y;
  static double  kx, ky,width, height;// the code could be wrote whothout all these vars, but I try to split the drawing line of code into smaller chunks

public CanvasView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if(inflater != null){       
        inflater.getContext();//this was the BIG problem
    }

    bmp=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.position);     
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas ) {

    super.onDraw(canvas);

    width = (double) getWidth();
    height = (double) getHeight();
    kx = (double)width/360;
    ky = (double)height/100;
    X = Math.round(ProcessAnalyser.H);
    Y = Math.round(ProcessAnalyser.L);


    setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.spectrum); 

    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, (float)(X *kx)-15, (float) (Y *ky)-15 , null);       

}

}
```

I guess this approach looks terrible for someone, but it works. The cross is repainted in a new place every time a new picture is taken on a samsung tablet with android 3. However if I  try it on a device with android 4, the cross stayes in 0,0 position.

Comment: I tried to put the H and L in a SQLite, but when trying to access them  it does not work to access the database from a View it looks like the SQLiteOpenHelper does not take a view as a parameter, it asks for a context.

Answer (score 0):

Sorted it out on my own so here is the answer. The problem was that the code in the canvas class was doing it's job, but only once.

```
X = Math.round(ProcessAnalyser.H);
Y = Math.round(ProcessAnalyser.L);
```

So the fact that the H and L were changing their values was not seen in the class CanvasView after the code in line

```
canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, (float)(X *kx)-15, (float) (Y *ky)-15 , null);
```

was executed. The answer was that the

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas ) {
```

method had to be wiped after it was done and redone again and again. This can be achieved by writing the line

```
invalidate();
```

at the end of the onDraw method.